# Jenkins job for non-java project

Tags: jenkins

I have created new Jenkins Job (Freestyle project) and my project repository has only few text files. In "Artifact Deployer" I have given "*.properties" (without quotes) in "Artifacts to deploy" text box and in "Remote file location" text box I entered "http://my.target.machine:8080/common/repos" (without quotes and is not same as my jenkins job machine). Build is successful but when I check "Last Succesful Deployed artifacts" I see the location as "/opt/jenkins/http:/my.target.machine:8080/common/repos". And also when I browse "http://my.target.machine:8080/common/repos" from my browser the artifacts are not listed. What might be the problem. Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: You artifacts are probably on this path on the jenkins server: `/opt/jenkins/http:/my.target.machine:8080/common/repos`..

Comment: But how do I get them to be uploaded to remote machine - "http://my.target.machine:8080/common/repos"

Comment: You'll probably need something like the publish over SSH plugin to access your remote server and scp the files to their destination.